# Chrome homescreen web app - Newsfeed link opening in browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, homescreen, progressive-web-apps

I recently followed Googles steps to have a simple homescreen web app going; something that gets created when I choose the "Add to Homescreen" option on an android with Chrome. The manifest helps define the icons and name and such, and most links within this standlone app thing stay within the app... except the /newsfeed page.

Whenever I click any link to get to the domain.com/newsfeed page on my site it opens it up in the Chrome browser instead. Every other link stays put within the homescreen app, including ones that lead off-site.

There's nothing special about that page as far as I can see; it doesn't have a target=_blank or any other details that aren't present on other links. My current guess is that somehow it reacts differently to links with "newsfeed" in them, thinking that I'm somehow incapable of handling dynamic content within the homescreen webapp.

Any ideas? It's not a HUGE deal, but I'd really rather know why that one page won't stay in the homescreen webapp.

Comment: Do you have a demo or code I can look at?